# How to learn how much you type in a day?

Tags: windows, keyboard, typing

Do you know of any software or script that helps you measure how much you type in a day, in terms of keys pressed? Maybe even do a bit of pattern analysis on those keys, etc. I'm interested on a solution that works on Windows and all keyboards, or as many keyboards as possible.

Appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Comment: My question is not answered. The solution mentioned there doesn't even work in Windows 7, let alone Windows 10. It is a 16-bit application that is not usable in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WhatPulse](http://whatpulse.org/) is a program that counts everything you might need to know, including programs that you have input, runtime, an activity keymap and various fun statistics.

Be wary that it's a potential keylogger (I used to run it back in the day, and forced it to be offline due to my own precautions).  However I have not heard any complains over the program.

Edit: It also counts uptime and such. You might want to disable some...or most.. of the features. :)

Comment: Looks interesting. I will definitely try it out and come back. Thank you!

Comment: WhatPulse is awesome. I've used it for a month now and I love the data that it shares, how much there is and how useful. I even wrote a guide about it, so that people who need such data can find it easily. Those of you that are interested, can read it here: [How many key presses and mouse clicks do you perform in a day?](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-many-key-presses-and-mouse-clicks-you-perform-day)